# How do I make it so that a line of code can be chosen, but not re-chosen after it has already been once

Tags: c++

I am looking for a way for the 'codee' to be able to select a certain branch of the code, but then not be able to select that code again. How would I do this? My code is essentially a game show, like jeopardy.

I've tried to use bool but I'm not very experienced. What I did was make "stop=true;" but it had no affect.

```
cin>>choose_1;
  if(choose_1==100){
    cout<<"You chose 100! Get it right for 100 points. //Obviously I put the question here

topics(); // brings you back to the topics list.
```

I want to be able to have the person be able to select "100" but not be able to select it again. How would I go about this?

Comment: Maybe `std::vector<bool>`

Comment: ***What I did was make "stop=true;" but it had no affect.*** Can you show an example of that? Your code does not show what you tried. Although with that said if you have a single stop bool variable it can be used for 1 question only.

Comment: Like I said, I am a beginner. Please keep that in mind while you read this. What I did was make stop = false and then I put a while statement so that whenever stop = true it would say something like "You already did that please do another." At the end of the question for 100 I put stop = false; Sorry I do not know how to make it code

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking about 2 ways:

1. Create vector/map or other container where you put all possible answers and thier rewards (or something like that) and where user select one of that you can firstly check if container have that element ( std::find(container.begin(), container.end(), userChoose) != container.end()) and erase this element of container.
2. Store all user chooses in container. and after user select number you must check if container contains that numer or not

## edit

Please take look at std::vector or std::set. You can easy store used numbers and check is not chosen numbers was previously used.